# How to use asynchronous ViewModel in every controller action?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asynchronous, viewmodel

I'm new to asp.net mvc (5) and I am facing an issue on my website.

Basically, all `aspnet_users` are linked to my specific `user` table via the `guid`.

I have a `BaseController` class with a `UnitOfWork` and a `ViewModelBase` :

```
public class BaseController : Controller
{
    protected UnitOfWork UnitOfWork { get; private set; }
    public ViewModelBase ViewModel { get; set; }
}
```

(Extract of) the `ViewModelBase` class, containing the information needed in the layout page :

```
public class ViewModelBase
{
    public User User { get; set; }
    public bool IsAuthentified { get; set; }
    public bool Loaded { get; set; }
}
```

And the layout which uses it :

```
@model Project.ViewModels.ViewModelBase
<html>
    <body>
        Some very cool layout stuff related to the User in the ViewModelBase
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is an example of use with the `HomeController` :

```
public class HomeController : BaseController
{
    private new HomeViewModel ViewModel
    {
        get { return (HomeViewModel)base.ViewModel; }
    }

    public HomeController()
    {
        ViewModel = new HomeViewModel();
    }

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        // I need to get the MembershipUser here to retrieve the related User and set it in the ViewModel
        return View(ViewModel);
    }
}
```

The `HomeViewModel` :

```
public class HomeViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public string HomeSpecificProperty { get; set; }
}
```

And the view :

```
@model Project.ViewModels.HomeViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/Layout.cshtml";
}

Welcome @Model.User.UserName !
<br />
@Model.HomeSpecificProperty
```

And here is my problem. The thing is all the pages have a viewmodel inherited from `ViewModelBase`, since it is used in the layout, but I don't know where nor how to set the `User` property in it.
Since `Membership` is used to retrieve the `User` it has to be in an `Action`, I can't do this in the `ViewModelBase` constructor.

Thus I added this code in the `BaseController`, which sets the `ViewModelBase` properties on the first `get` :

```
private ViewModelBase viewModel;

protected ViewModelBase ViewModel
{
    get
    {
        if (!viewModel.Loaded)
            LoadBaseContext();

        return viewModel;
    }
    set { viewModel = value; }
}

private void LoadBaseContext()
{
    viewModel.IsAuthentified = HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated;

    if (viewModel.IsAuthentified)
    {
        MembershipUser user = Membership.GetUser();
        viewModel.Player = UnitOfWork.UserRepo.Get((Guid)user.ProviderUserKey);
    }

    viewModel.Loaded = true;
}
```

Might not be very beautiful, but works. However, since there is some database acesses in it (notably to get the `User`), I thought I should put the `LoadBaseContext` function `async`.
I tried, and since all actions use `ViewModelBase` I put every action async too. But then `@Html.ActionLink` doesn't work anymore since the action called is `async`.

Finally, my question is : Is this `ViewModelBase` and `User` property the right way to do ? If it is, should the `LoadBaseContext` be async ? Then, how to make it work with the actions ?

Thanks a lot.

***UPDATE***

Extract of the layout :

```
@if (!Model.IsAuthentified)
{
    @Html.Action("Index", "Authentification", null) // display login partial view
}
else
{
    @Html.Action("Index", "UserInfos", null) // display userinfos partial view
}
```

Authentification controller Index's action :

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    ViewModel = new AuthentificationViewModel();
    // loads the ViewModelBase properties here
    return PartialView("~/Views/Shared/Partials/Login.cshtml", ViewModel);
}
```

Comment: There is no `async` properties in C#... so if you need to make part of property `async` you have to make it into method... And if you really want to make code async you have to perform such operation in asynchronous top level actions (can't call async methods asynchronously from views/child actions in MVC5)

Comment: Thanks for your comment, yeah I read about it but I don't understand what I could do. I need to call my actions from views (`@Html.ActionLink` for instance), so they must be sync. But if all actions are sync, how can I asynchronously load my `User` from it ? It won't work unless the action is async too if I understand well. Thus must I forget about getting the user asynchronously ?

Comment: @Flash_Back: you may want to look at my "one final word" update (in case you missed it).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have something that you always want in all of your views, you could either ensure that every view takes a view model that includes or extends that core set of data, *or* you could simply put the data in the `ViewBag`.

To do the latter, you could override `OnActionExecuting` in your base controller, and set the `ViewBag` contents there.

```
protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
{
    base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    this.ViewBag["IsAuthenticated"] = this.Request.IsAuthenticated;
    // ...
}
```

If you want `async` behaviour, then you might be able to adapt [this post](http://www.strathweb.com/2013/11/asynchronous-action-filters-asp-net-web-api/) to your needs.

To do this without overriding `OnActionExecuting`, you could put an `async` method in your controller base class that sets the data in the `ViewBag`:

```
protected async virtual Task PopulateViewBag()
{
    this.ViewBag["foo"] = await MyAsyncMethod();

    // ...
}
```

... and then simply call this from each and every one of your controller actions:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> MyAction()
{
    await this.PopulateViewBag();

    // ... more code
}
```

It would be a bit tedious, though.

**One final word:** depending on how many users you expect to have etc. it may be easier to get the user information *once*, and then cache it (e.g. in the `Session`), rather than repeatedly get it during every request. Presumably most of the user info isn't going to change between requests...

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer ! I didn't know about `OnActionExecuting` method, this will actually allow to extract the loading from the `getter`, which was not relevant. If I understand, replacing the `ViewModelBase` by the `ViewBag` will permit to set the `User` asynchronously while leaving the actions sync to avoid exceptions on `@Html.ActionLink`, is that right ?

Comment: Sorry, I'd actually missed the part about it being async (despite that being in the title). I'm not sure that you *can* do it in OnActionExecuting, then, because that's not an async method. Let me update my answer with an alternative.

Comment: Thanks for your update. Seems great, however I already tried a similar solution (making all the actions `async`) but then I can't use `@Html.ActionLink` anymore because I read I can't call async actions from views. Or did I misunderstood ?

Comment: That's not true - you can link to an action using `ActionLink` whether it's `async` or not. What you can't do is *invoke* an `async` method in a view, but you're not invoking it, you're only building a URL that refers to it.

Comment: Can I ? Oh right, I misunderstood this point. I do have an `HttpServerUtility.Execute` exception on an `ActionLink` in the layout when the related action is async, but I guess this is not related to it being async. Thanks a lot, I'll investigate this !

Comment: @Flash_Back: if you're trying to *execute* the action, then that's... not going to work. :-)  But if you're trying to do that, you probably shouldn't be.

Comment: About your final word, I actually get the `User` but also its related entities using `EF` (Inbox for example, to know if there is any new message). If I cache it will I still be able to reload this information when the user changes page ?
Well I'm pretty new so I don't really know if I execute it, I edited my first post and put the layout code with the `@Html.ActionLink` raising exception when the action is async, and the related controller. I think I could use `@Html.Partial` directly but I need to go the action to build the ViewModel used in the partial view.
Anyway thanks for your help !

Comment: @Flash_Back: you should get *once* (and cache) the things that (a) won't change, and (b) are used in every action. If there's stuff that (a) does change between requests, or (b) is only needed by certain actions, then you'll need to get those as-required. I wouldn't get *everything* for *every* request, though!